# I can't debug Raspberry pico with C++ into VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, raspberry-pi-pico

I generate the file elf fine , but when I try to debug show me this on TERMINAL:

> Waiting for gdb server to start...[2022-05-08T07:24:22.096Z] SERVER CONSOLE DEBUG: onBackendConnect: gdb-server session connected.
> You can switch to "DEBUG CONSOLE" to see GDB interactions.
> "C:/msys64/home/Martin/openocd/src/openocd.exe" -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s
> "C:/msys64/home/Martin/openocd/tcl" -f
> "c:/Users/radio/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.4.4/support/openocd-helpers.tcl"
> -f interface/picoprobe.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg
> **[2022-05-08T07:24:22.137Z] SERVER CONSOLE DEBUG: onBackendConnect: gdb-server session closed
> GDB server session ended. This terminal will be reused, waiting for next session to start...**

Debug Console:

```
Reading symbols from arm-none-eabi-objdump --syms -C -h -w D:\pico\pico-projects\HelloWorldPicoGenerator\build\HelloWorldPicoGenerator.elf
Reading symbols from arm-none-eabi-nm --defined-only -S -l -C -p D:\pico\pico-projects\HelloWorldPicoGenerator\build\HelloWorldPicoGenerator.elf
Launching GDB: arm-none-eabi-gdb -q --interpreter=mi2 "D:\\pico\\pico-projects\\HelloWorldPicoGenerator\\build\\HelloWorldPicoGenerator.elf"
1-gdb-set target-async on
Launching gdb-server: "C:/msys64/home/Martin/openocd/src/openocd.exe" -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s "C:/msys64/home/Martin/openocd/tcl" -f "c:/Users/radio/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.4.4/support/openocd-helpers.tcl" -f interface/picoprobe.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg
    Please check TERMINAL tab (gdb-server) for output from C:/msys64/home/Martin/openocd/src/openocd.exe
Finished reading symbols from objdump: Time: 49 ms
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2020-q4-major\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe: warning: Couldn't determine a path for the index cache directory.
Finished reading symbols from nm: Time: 55 ms
-> =thread-group-added,id="i1"
-> ~"Reading symbols from D:\\pico\\pico-projects\\HelloWorldPicoGenerator\\build\\HelloWorldPicoGenerator.elf...\n"
Reading symbols from D:\pico\pico-projects\HelloWorldPicoGenerator\build\HelloWorldPicoGenerator.elf...
-> 1^done
2-gdb-version
-> ~"GNU gdb (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10-2020-q4-major) 10.1.90.20201028-git\n"
-> ~"Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
-> ~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\nThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law."
-> ~"\nType \"show copying\" and \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
-> ~"This GDB was configured as \"--host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi\".\n"
-> ~"Type \"show configuration\" for configuration details.\n"
-> ~"For bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"
-> ~"<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.\n"
-> ~"Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:\n    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>."
-> ~"\n\n"
-> ~"For help, type \"help\".\n"
-> ~"Type \"apropos word\" to search for commands related to \"word\".\n"
-> 2^done
3-interpreter-exec console "set print demangle on"
OpenOCD GDB Server Quit Unexpectedly. See gdb-server output for more details.
```

And this is my launch.json:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387

  //       "executable": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Cortex Debug",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "executable": "${workspaceRoot}\\build\\HelloWorldPicoGenerator.elf",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "cortex-debug",
      "servertype": "openocd",
      "gdbPath": "arm-none-eabi-gdb",
      "device": "RP2040",
      "configFiles": [
        "interface/picoprobe.cfg",
        "target/rp2040.cfg"],
      "svdFile": "${env:PICO_SDK_PATH}/src/rp2040/hardware_regs/rp2040.svd",
      "showDevDebugOutput": "raw",
      "postRestartCommands": [
          "break main",
          "continue"
      ],
      "searchDir": ["C:/msys64/home/Martin/openocd/tcl"],
    }
  ]
}
```

Please someone has same error?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the path to Mingw-w64 bin folder ( which is `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` in my case) to the Windows `PATH` environment. That solved the problem in my case.